# `airflow dags list` is limiting number of character of dag_id

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to list dag_ids using airflow command given below

`airflow dags list`

The above command is indeed working but it is not showing entire dag_id(showing only first 30 characters of the dag).

I tried to check documentation but couldn't find anything that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, below is the command

`airflow dags list -o yaml | grep dag_id | awk '{print $3}'`